# How to use VBA to incorporate functions to avoid occupation of extra cells?

Tags: excel, vba

This spreadsheet aims to calculate distances between atoms, and we want to improve the functions so as to avoid the occupation of extra columns. (See image postscripted.[image: Atom coordinates are given in the Column A to D, and the atom pair whose distance should be calculated is given in Column F to G.] Atom coordinates are given in the Column A to D, and the atom pair whose distance should be calculated is given in Column F to G.)

Currently in the first step, coordinates of specified atoms are picked up in columns I to O. e.g. Cell I4 is filled with the function:

`=VLOOKUP($F4,$A$4:$E$1023,2,FALSE)`

and then in the next step, the distance could be resolved in Column Q with Euclidean distance formula on the coordinates picked up. e.g. Cell Q4 is:

`=SQRT(POWER((I4-M4),2)+POWER((J4-N4),2)+POWER((K4-O4),2))`

According to the distance calculating algorithm, once the two atoms are specified, the distance is then determined. Thus, **is it possible to write a function with VBA to gracefully incorporate these functions and take away these pilot processes from columns I to O?** (Because these columns will be used otherwise in the future; and the code readability would be terrible if we put, for example, the six VLOOKUP functions directly into the final SQRT function.)

I'm new to VBA. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The original data in this spreadsheet is as below: (From the third line)

```
Atom_No X_coordinate    Y_coordinate    Z_coordinate        Atom_No1    Atom_No2        X1  Y1  Z1      X2  Y2  Z2      Distance
1   2.35739851  13.17160225 4.022993565     4   2       3.827347994 9.501971245 8.374602318     4.403610706 11.14351559 6.991936684     2.222276039
2   4.403610706 11.14351559 6.991936684     3   2       0.721047342 12.58075523 2.64032793      4.403610706 11.14351559 6.991936684     5.879067059
3   0.721047342 12.58075523 2.64032793      1   4       2.35739851  13.17160225 4.022993565     3.827347994 9.501971245 8.374602318     5.879068118
4   3.827347994 9.501971245 8.374602318     2   1       4.403610706 11.14351559 6.991936684     2.35739851  13.17160225 4.022993565     4.13699687
…   …   …   …       3   1       0.721047342 12.58075523 2.64032793      2.35739851  13.17160225 4.022993565     2.22227577
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, these two modules will work and get the correct result when CoordinateTableRange and Atom_No1-2 pair is given like this table. You could load these two modules, and write in column R (e.g. R4 cell) with

```
=AtomsDistance(F4,G4)
```

, then you'll find the distance is the same as you got in col Q.

```
Function CoordinateVLookUp(Atom_No As Integer, CoordinateTableRange As Range, Column As Integer, isFuzzy As Boolean) As Double
    'To find the atom coordinates according to columns, with CoordinateTableRange selected and isFuzzy specified.

    Dim myResult As Variant
    myResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Atom_No, CoordinateTableRange, Column, isFuzzy)
    If IsError(myResult) Then
        MsgBox ("No result found.")
    Else
        CoordinateVLookUp = myResult
    End If

End Function
```

```
Function AtomsDistance(Atom_No1 As Integer, Atom_No2 As Integer) As Double
    'To call CoordinateVLookUp function above to acquire the x, y, z coordinates of both atoms, and then calculate the distance through Euclidean distance formula. 

    Dim x1 As Double
    Dim y1 As Double
    Dim z1 As Double

    Dim x2 As Double
    Dim y2 As Double
    Dim z2 As Double
    
    Dim CoordinateTableRange As Range
    Set CoordinateTableRange = Range("A4:E1023") 'set should be added
            
    x1 = CoordinateVLookUp(Atom_No1, CoordinateTableRange, 2, False)
    y1 = CoordinateVLookUp(Atom_No1, CoordinateTableRange, 3, False)
    z1 = CoordinateVLookUp(Atom_No1, CoordinateTableRange, 4, False)
    
    x2 = CoordinateVLookUp(Atom_No2, CoordinateTableRange, 2, False)
    y2 = CoordinateVLookUp(Atom_No2, CoordinateTableRange, 3, False)
    z2 = CoordinateVLookUp(Atom_No2, CoordinateTableRange, 4, False)
    
    AtomsDistance = Math.Sqr((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2) + (z1 - z2) * (z1 - z2))
    
End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and I've tried to improve it with this new editted version.